# AWS lambda or AWS batch to delete rows from dynamo DB based on certain criteria

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-batch

I have a requirement where I need to delete records based on criteria it doesn't need to be real time, the records are stored in dynamo DB. Can AWS lambda be scheduled ex run every day @ 11pm can I package a cron job or is it better to go with AWS batch only worry with batch is it has more overheads.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If your criteria is **time** then the best option is to use the Time To Live (TTL).
DynamoDB TTL feature delete a records after expiry.

> TTL is useful if you store items that lose relevance after a specific
> time. The following are example TTL use cases:
>
> - Remove user or sensor data after one year of inactivity in an application.
> - Archive expired items to an Amazon S3 data lake via Amazon DynamoDB    Streams and AWS Lambda.
> - Retain sensitive data for a certain amount of time according to    contractual or regulatory obligations.

AWS provides details in [this document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/TTL.html).

If instead you have more complex criteria, you could use Lambda as you requested, however creating a Lambda function alone won't be enough.
In fact Lambda need always something to kick it off, like a cron job.
**AWS recommends to use CloudWatch to schedule Lambda runs.** Relevant documentation can be found in the tutorial "[Schedule AWS Lambda Functions Using CloudWatch Events](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/events/RunLambdaSchedule.html)"
This process includes the following steps:

1. **Create an AWS Lambda Function** to log the scheduled events. Specify this function when you create your rule.
2. **Create a rule in CloudWatch** to run your Lambda function on a schedule.
   A rule would look like:

   aws events put-rule 
   --name my-scheduled-rule 
   --schedule-expression 'rate(5 minutes)'
3. **Verify the rule** checking that your Lambda function was invoked.

Comment: Worth noting that DynamoDB does not guarantee to delete items at the time their TTL expires but "TTL typically deletes expired items within 48 hours of expiration."